# Synology DSM 7.2 cannot add iptables LOG rule

Tags: iptables, synology, rules

When trying to add a LOG rule to iptables on Synology DSM 7.2 the following error is thrown:

> iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

Verified that LOG module is loaded, rule is valid, chain is present etc.

It seems impossible to add this rule and I cannot get my head around as to why.

I have tried a lot of possible root causes but nothing seems to help.

```
root@server:~# iptables -v -I INPUT_FIREWALL 1 -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix '--Firewall--' --log-level notice
LOG  all opt -- in * out *  0.0.0.0/0  -> 0.0.0.0/0   limit: avg 2/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 5 prefix "--Firewall--"
LOG  all opt -- in * out *  0.0.0.0/0  -> 0.0.0.0/0   limit: avg 2/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 5 prefix "--Firewall--"
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

root@server:/ha# cat /proc/net/ip_tables_targets
MARK
DNAT
SNAT
REDIRECT
DNAT
SNAT
MASQUERADE
LOG
ERROR
root@server:/ha# cat /proc/net/ip_tables_names
mangle
nat
filter

root@server:~# iptables -V
iptables v1.8.3 (legacy)

root@server:~# iptables -L -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 5893 packets, 356K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  15M 3850M DOS_PROTECT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 342K   83M INPUT_FIREWALL  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 176K   28M FORWARD_FIREWALL  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
1066K  148M DEFAULT_FORWARD  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 329K packets, 82M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DEFAULT_FORWARD (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1064K  147M DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
1064K  147M DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 1783  520K ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 280K   97M DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 782K   50M ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 280K   97M ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:8883

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 782K   50M DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
1064K  147M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 782K   50M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1064K  147M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOS_PROTECT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 RETURN     icmp --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8 limit: avg 1000/sec burst 5
    0     0 DROP       icmp --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8

Chain FORWARD_FIREWALL (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 164K   26M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 RETURN     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3000
    0     0 RETURN     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 3478,10001
    0     0 RETURN     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 6789,8080,8443,8880
    0     0 RETURN     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:514
    0     0 RETURN     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain INPUT_FIREWALL (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 218K   47M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
97901   30M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 RETURN     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3000
    0     0 RETURN     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 3478,10001
 4352  236K RETURN     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 6789,8080,8443,8880
    0     0 RETURN     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:514
    0     0 RETURN     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
19888 4919K DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```